# How can I get systemd to wait for Avahi to completely stop at shutdown/reboot time?

Tags: systemd, avahi

Specifically, I've got some code that consumes the output of avahi-browse on another machine and occasionally it doesn't see all of the services stopping when a server powers down or reboots.  Generally most of them come through, but not always.  It seems that systemd is too aggressive about stopping networking.